# Is there an English version of Johann Bernoulli's integral calculus lectures?

Tags: calculus, reference-request, soft-question, math-history

The name of lectures of integral calculus written by Johann or Jeans Bernoulli (he is called by both names as far as I know) might be " lecciones mathematicæ de calculo integral"; I must mention that, this is not the complete name of book, but a part of the name; as so many editions have come, it is difficult to say the name.

I searched for one day for the english translation, I couldn't even find the english title of his book on integral calculus. I found his books called Opera Omnia, in [latin](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1148875638) and [French](https://archive.org/details/bub_gb_pbvMLAqS5OoC), which contains these lectures, but onceagain, I couldn't even find a single english edition. I am really in need of his book, as he was the first to study lebnizian calculus; ofcourse Jackob Bernoulli also studied with Johann Bernoulli.

I want to know nothing but the title of english edition of his calculus lectures and the name of the translator of it, if possible, even the downloadable version of it.

I already have english editon of L'Hopital's book on differential calculus called "[Analyse des Infinements Petits](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3319171143)" (claimed to be the first textbook on differential calculus) which contains Johann Bernoulli's lectures on differential calculus titled "Lectiones de Calculo Differentials", but it doesn't contain lectures on integral calculus. **If possible can anyone also point out some of the oldest books on "integral calculus".**

Edit (6/6/17): Google's "Play Books" app has translator, which translates books in most of the languages being offline. This is the optimal solution I have found till now.

Comment: I have another copy of L'Hopital's book on differential calculus, translated by Edmund Stone; it contains intergration concept, but not of Bernoulli, but of Stone, given as appendix.

Comment: I found english editions of Opera omnia, which doesn't contain integration lectures [here](http://www.amazon.com/Johannis-Bernoulli-Sparsim-Hactenus-Inedita/dp/1174546387/ref=sr_1_2?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1440214603&sr=1-2&keywords=opera+omnia+english+bernoulli) and [here](http://www.amazon.com/Johannis-Bernoulli-Opera-Omnia-Continentur/dp/1173038086/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1440214750&sr=1-1&keywords=opera+omnia+english+bernoulli). But, at last, it gives me hope and hope for others to search for the english version of integral calculus.

Comment: There is a book by Edward which Ramanujan studied

Comment: Omg, Hermann Hesse lived in same city, Basel. Well nevermind there exists this Project Gutenberg with many old books online for free. http://www.gutenberg.org

Comment: Could this be what you're looking for? https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/0020739X.2018.1543810?scroll=top&needAccess=true&journalCode=tmes20 this is a great question, I don't know if this is the whole thing.

Comment: @BenjaminThoburn: Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no English translation of Bernoulli's integral calculus lectures. There is a partial but quite comprehensive translation into German ([Die erste Integralrechnung](https://archive.org/details/dieersteintegra00kowagoog), tr. Kowalewski).

Since Bernoulli's lectures remained unpublished until 1742, the first published book on the integral calculus was Gabriele Manfredi's De constructione aequationum differentialium primi gradus (1707). This work has also never been translated into English or any other language.

Comment: But, I found few minutes ago, english version of opera omnia which contains integral calculus, but it is not available for free download, I am searching for that site, if I find, I will give the link. Next goal is to find free downloadable version of Opera omnia...

Comment: Here is the link to the (apparently dummy) site: http://www.alibris.com/search/books/isbn/9781274078018?qwork=17938101 The title of the book contains the name, "Accedunt Lectiones Mathematicae de Calculo Integralium", so I think it contains integration lectures.

Comment: I have done quite a bit of research on the early history of the calculus. If there was an English translation I would know about it. The book you link to is clearly a reprint of the Opera. It is in Latin, not English.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Sorry if it is misleading, once again, I clicked on that link, I scrolled down and I clicked on the book Nabu 2012 (among the three books given there), it takes to details of the book, where the language is written as English, if it is really the English edition (though title is in other language), it is really a very very good news for us, please check it once again...

Comment: For the last time: there is no English translation. The fact that it says "Language: English" on such websites obviously means nothing, since those are not properly published books but rather automatically generated attempts at making money by printing readily available PDFs of out-of-copyright works.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation. I hope to read Bernoulli book in future...